# To convert date format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, datetime

How can I convert a date present in format `2017-06-30 23:59:59.000` to `JUNE 2017`?

I need to do this using SQL Query.

Comment: does `date_format()` not work in your dbms?

Comment: @ArpitaDutta, please check my answer.

Comment: FYI if you are correctly storing your datetime value in a `datetime` datatype, then it has no display format, its stored as binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DATENAME` function will return the Name of the month

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,'2017-06-30 23:59:59.000')+' '+CAST(YEAR('2017-06-30 23:59:59.000') AS VARCHAR) 'Month Name'
SELECT DATENAME(mm,'2017-06-30 23:59:59.000')+' '+CAST(YEAR('2017-06-30 23:59:59.000') AS VARCHAR) 'Month Name'
SELECT DATENAME(m,'2017-06-30 23:59:59.000')+' '+CAST(YEAR('2017-06-30 23:59:59.000') AS VARCHAR) 'Month Name'
```

This will return

```
June 2017
```

If you want to get it from a table, then replace the table and column name in the below query.

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,ColumnName)+' '+CAST(YEAR(ColumnName) AS VARCHAR) 'Month Name' 
FROM TabeName
```

Answer (score 4):

**You can use the `FORMAT` function for this**

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2017-06-30 23:59:59.000' AS datetime), 'MMMM yyyy');
```

Result

```
June 2017
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/130489)

Comment: I also like `FORMAT` solution, but with one small change: `MMMM yy` instead of `MMM yy` (to get `JUNE`, not `JUN`). +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

The DATENAME function in sql server returns the name of the month.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR()) AS 
                                                                   [Month YYYY]
```

For more information you can refer: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best answer for MS SQL.

```
Create table Test(
SampleDate datetime
)
insert into Test(SampleDate)values('07/20/2021 10:20:05'),('08/21/2021 20:30:11')
```

Here is your query to get the format

```
select FORMAT(SampleDate, 'MMMM yyyy') YourFormat from Test
--select FORMAT(SampleDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt') EditedDate from Test
```

[You can see the output here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/138a8/2/0)

**Above query return the following output:**

July 2021

August 2021

Answer (score -2):

SELECT **DATE_FORMAT(column_name, "%M %Y")** as **alias_column_name** FROM **tabel_name**

**Example**

SELECT **DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %Y")** as **created_at** FROM **tabel1**

use sql's **DATE_FORMAT(date, format)** function.

https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_date_format.asp <- visit this website.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/ <- **Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server**

[image]

Comment: I don't think `DATE_FORMAT' is an SQL Server built-in function.